# What is best practice for building stored procedure with various parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i'm trying to build stored procedure which dynamically build me a query depends on provided parameters

for initial requirements i had 2 parameters which are switchable, and 3rd one which is optional i did this

```
PROCEDURE `myProcedure`(IN pred1 int(11),IN pred2 varchar(45),IN pred3 datetime)
BEGIN
DECLARE idx int(11) DEFAULT 0;
set  @query := ' SELECT *  FROM `mytable` where  ';

SET @a = "" ; 

IF pred1 is not null THEN  
SET @a = pred1;
SET @query = CONCAT(@query,' and field1 = ? ' );
END IF;

 IF pred2 is not null THEN  
SET @a = pred2;
SET @query = CONCAT(@query,' and field2 = ? ' );
END IF;

 IF pred3 is not null THEN  
SET @b = pred3;
SET @query = CONCAT(@query,' and field3 = ? ' );
END IF;

 PREPARE stmt FROM @query; 

 IF pred3 is not null THEN  
    EXECUTE stmt USING @a, @b 
    ELSE
    EXECUTE stmt USING @a;
END IF;
END
```

now my specs changed and all of the parameters are optional, what will be best practice to save issue like mine?

Comment: The best practice is to not use SQL to build SQL. What benefit does any of this provide over doing it all in the application layer?

Comment: @tadman my primary requirement is to prevent application from having direct access to tables, hence all db interaction must be done via stored procedures. now call me lazy, but i don't want to create 3 stored procedures to execute same query with different search predicates. hence i'm asking about better way. of course i could do predicates such as `(field1 = param1 or param1 is null)` but this solution looks more dirty to me than that what i'm doing now.

Comment: What's the motivation behind preventing the application from having access to tables? This sort of "no queries for you" approach is something straight out of the playbook of a 1980s DBA overly concerned about job security, so I'd be sure you're not getting too heavy handed here.

Comment: @tadman decision on restricting access to the tables is mainly based on security reasons.

Comment: That's what the application layer is for. If you can't trust the application layer you need middleware.

Comment: @tadman i agree with you, but as i said earlier using stored procedure is part of my requirements.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm also saying this is a losing battle. When people do go down this road they create a very rigid "API" of sorts using stored procedures and they avoid creating arbitrary "query composer" type ones because they get extremely complicated almost right out of the gate. Getting this code audited to make sure it doesn't contain holes is going to be a never-ending task.

Comment: You probably want to auto-generate these procedures from a template using a script and a schema definition. That way you can be sure you don't make a slip somewhere, introduce a typo or a hole by accident. Verifying one of them gives you a lot of confidence in the other derivative methods.

Comment: @tadman so there is no other way than have procedure for each combinations of possible predicates?

Comment: Unless you want a procedure that composes queries, yes. These rigid, unyielding requirements for "only stored procedures, no queries for you" lead to an unfathomably bad mess of procedures to try and cover off all the common cases. I've seen shops run like this, under the thumb of some tyrant DBA who doesn't trust "developers", and it's always misery.